# Compare user ID exactly, not with LIKE

Tags: compare, sql-like, advanced-custom-fields

I have this query -

```
<?php
        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
            'tax_query' => array(

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'compliance',
                    ),
                        ),

                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'associated_people',
                                'value' => $current_user,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                    )
                ); ?>
```

At the moment it is fetching events that are associated to a particular person in a custom post type called `people`. I'm doing this using a relationship advanced custom field called `associated_people`.

I'm using the `'compare' => 'LIKE'` code to do this also, but it's fetching other id's that are like the current one. e.g. If it's looking for ID 117, it's also bringing back 17, 11, 7..etc.

Is there a way to look at just the exact ID?

So far we have tried changing it to `'compare' => '='`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by changing the way the value was called -

```
<?php
    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
        'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
        'tax_query' => array(

            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'compliance',
                ),
                    ),

                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'associated_people',
                            'value' => '"' . $current_user . '"',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            ); ?>
```